# Database suitable for data mining

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

What would be an appropriate / suitable database sans Oracle that would be suitable for the following conditions?

1. data mining
    includes but does not limit to the following:
    a. clicking on links
    b. capture geolocation data, platform details
    c. user behaviours
2. there will be a foreseen exponential surge of data being captured as more apps / sites being deployed
3. for now, there are on average 60,000 ~ 80,000 data being captured every 15 minutes for 2 main sites / apps
4. In the near future, we are also planning to release all these data to the various parties involved where they can use it for their own apps / sites.

As of now, we are using mySQL but we found that it becomes very costly as we started to scale up. As such, any advice would be good as a starting point.

Comment: maybe you should start with what budget is available and what storage solution fits that.

Comment: I'm not sure about storage solution, hence I'm asking that question. As for budget, as low as possible if not 0. Mainly because we are investing most of our resources on bandwidth and we already have 2 racks of server space available for our own use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahout with HBase is probably a good option for very large datasets.

It is designed to run on many cheap commodity servers.

Also, [monetDB](http://www.monetdb.org/Home) is an open-source column-wise database which is very fast for data warehouses.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at that. I have read up hadoop briefly. Will that also be appropriate in our requirements?

Comment: Hadoop is a distributed file system and parallel processing framework. It could do what you want to do. HBase and Mahout build on top of Hadoop. HBase allows for random access reads (it's a database on top of Hadoop), and Mahout is a distributed data mining library that can use Hadoop or HBase.